# Recursive function for sum

Tags: c, recursion, parameters

I have this recursive function, and I try to pass the result in 's' variable.
However if I use `*s=*s+v[i];` the function works.
But if I try to call `sum(v,i+2,s+v[i],n);` It doesn't work anymore.
Can someone tell me what is wrong?
Here is the code:

```
void sum(int v[], int i, int *s, int n)
{
    if (i < n)
    {
        if (v[i] < 0)
        {
            //*s = *s + v[i];
            //sum(v, i + 2, s, n);
            sum(v, i + 2, s + v[i], n);

        }
        else
            sum(v, i + 2, s, n);
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n = 7;
    int v[] = { -5,-8,4,4,3,9,-5 };
    int i = 0;
    int s = 0;
    sum(v, i, &s, n);
    printf("SUM IS: %d", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain: sum of what?

Comment: `s + v[i]` surely is wrong. Do you have warnings of your compiler turned on?

Comment: Your function doesn’t return anything, so if you change it so that it only calls itself and never writes to anything… what do you think `s + v[i]` does?

Comment: Negative numbers whose position in vector is multiple of 2

Comment: I have no errors, here is what i get
First value is v[i] and second is s
-5 ~ 0 / 
4 ~ -858993460 / 
3 ~ -858993460 / 
-5 ~ -858993460 / 
SUM IS: 0

Comment: When you don't pass a pointer, the variables in the caller do not change... in `bar = <something>; foo(bar); /*bar is still <something>*/` whatever `foo()` and `bar` are the value of `bar` before and after the function is the same.

Comment: If recall the function like this (sum(v, i + 2, *s + v[i], n);) I get this error: E0167 argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *"

Comment: I don't know how to recall the function without this part `*s = *s + v[i];`
I want to update the s variable right in the next call `sum(etc, s+v[i],etc);`

Answer (score 2):

There is a major difference between to 2 ways.

1. The correct one:

   ```
   *s = *s +v[i];             // increases the int object pointed to by s
   sum(v, i + 2, s, n);       // still pass the same pointer to sum
   ```
2. The wrong one:

   ```
   sum(v, i+2, s+v[i], n);
   ```

   Here, the **pointer** is increased instead of the pointed object. It is equivalent to:

   ```
   s = s +v[i];               // s is not dereferenced here!
   sum(v, i + 2, s, n);       // pass an incorrect pointer to sum
   ```

Comment: so is not possible in this case to call the function in a similar way to `sum(v, i + 2, s + v[i] ,n);` ?
The only way is to add the array value to *s and then pass it to the function?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have multiple problems that need correction.

First of all, the inner `if` is not needed. It is unclear what you wanted to do with this. Handling negative numbers separately? If so, it is not needed since the `+` operator can also handle addition of negative numbers.

Secondly, the `s + v[i]` adds the value in your array to the *pointer to* sum, which is not what you want. You need to use the `*` operator to dereference `s` here so that the number is added to the sum that the pointer *points to*. Your own commented-out code does this correctly.

Thirdly, using `sum(v, i + 2, s, n);` skips alternate elements so to sum the whole array properly, you need to use `i + 1` instead of `i + 2`.

The following code fixes these issues.

```
void sum(int v[], int i, int *s, int n)
{
    if (i < n)
    {
        *s += v[i];
        sum(v, i + 1, s, n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 7;
    int v[] = { -5,-8,4,4,3,9,-5 };
    int i = 0;
    int s = 0;
    sum(v, i, &s, n);
    printf("SUM IS: %d", s);
    return 0;
}
```